# Qt QFileDialog multiple files from multiple directories

Tags: qt, qfiledialog

Is there a way to allow the user to select multiple files from different directories?

Comment: nop, not is possible

Comment: You could probably do what you want quite easily with a combination of [`QFileSystemModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html) and [`QTreeView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html).  Better still, why not enable [drag-and-drop](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/dnd.html) in your application?  Then users can simply select the files they want in their favourite file browser and drag them across.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Qt documentation, it is not possible

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html